# Error upgrading Rails from 3.0.9 to 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, runtime-error

I followed the Railscast guide to updating to Rails 3.2 by changing my rails to 3.2.0 in my gem file and doing bundle update and it installs everything successfully, but when I run anything I get this extremely long error message. Here is the first part.

```
WARNING:  #<ArgumentError: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fa232a830f0> 3.2.0"]>
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{actionmailer}
  s.version = "3.2.0"
```

Here is another part of the error message that I was able to pick out

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec'
WARNING:  #<ArgumentError: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x007fa2327b5e68> 3.2.0"]>
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{railties}
  s.version = "3.2.0"
```

I then ran rails s, just to see if I would get the same message, which I did, but at the end this is what I was told to do

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec'
Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be a rubygems issue, can you try upgrading rubygems and see if that fixes it? Also, just a recommendation, but I would upgrade to rails 3.2.9 rather than 3.2.0 as it contains some important security fixes.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but try clearing out all your gems, deleting your Gemfile.lock (or better yet, moving it out of the way, so you can restore if need be), and running bundle then.  Seems like something got corrupted along the way, somehow.

Comment: I tried running bundle, but the same error came up

Comment: What I meant is that I attempted to delete all of my gems and the Gemfile.lock and the same error came up

Comment: Upgrading rubygems did not fix anything as well